What happens during lobbying sessions?
I learned only recently that the word "lobby" was originally meant to describe soliciting members of the judiciary branch of government for favors. I suspect that lobbying toward the executive branch is much harder because the distinction between lobbying and bribery begins to blur.
I decided to look at the disclosed list of lobby events as per the Disclosure Act of 1995. However, looking through the list, I find that the details are mostly missing; i.e. "education programs on prime vendor", "business reform" and so forth...the wording is very vague as well. The contributions are much smaller than I'd thought, nothing like campaign contributions.
What really goes on in these lobbying sessions?

Is there something specific that isn't clear about how Wikipedia describes it?

Can you provide, excerpt, or link to this list of lobby events? How recent is the list? What sort of events are on it?

Lobby in reference to the judicial branch is extremely archaic. This would be back in pre-modern England. I don't think it was ever a practice, for example, in the U.S. Even when it happens these days, it isn't acknowledged as such or described that way.

'I suspect that lobbying toward the executive branch is much harder because the distinction between lobbying and bribery begins to blur." This makes no sense.

Figuratively speaking it's the attempt to catch a politician in the lobby (apparently historically in the hallway of parliament during breaks) and have a talk about politics with them, with the intent to try to influence them in your favor. So in other words it's a form of direct political advocacy.

originally meant to describe soliciting members of the judiciary branch of government for favors.

Usually the judiciary is its own branch, while the government is the (leading) part of the executive branch. But either way lobbying can effect all positions of power (executive, legislative, judiciary, all kinds of regulators, etc), where people try to get a better outcome by positioning their advocates close to the people who make the decisions to make sure their arguments are heard and accounted for.
It's more like what happens before and after the campaign contributions where individuals or groups, amateurs or professionals try to "educate" politicians as to "what's best for ... e.g. the economy (and usually them in particular)" and if it's controversial maybe also how they wish them to sell it to the general public.
Here's for example a rundown of tactics that advocacy groups might employ to restrict regulations:

Efforts to prevent noncommunicable diseases go against the business interests of powerful economic operators. In my view, this is one of the biggest challenges facing health promotion. [...] it is not just Big Tobacco anymore. Public health must also contend with Big Food, Big Soda, and Big Alcohol. All of these industries fear regulation, and protect themselves by using the same tactics. Research has documented these tactics well. They include front groups, lobbies, promises of self-regulation, lawsuits, and industry-funded research that confuses the evidence and keeps the public in doubt. Tactics also include gifts, grants, and contributions to worthy causes that cast these industries as respectable corporate citizens in the eyes of politicians and the public. They include arguments that place the responsibility for harm to health on individuals, and portray government actions as interference in personal liberties and free choice. This is formidable opposition. [...] When industry is involved in policy-making, rest assured that the most effective control measures will be downplayed or left out entirely. This, too, is well documented, and dangerous. In the view of WHO, the formulation of health policies must be protected from distortion by commercial or vested interests. (source)

The problem with those are usually not so much direct bribery though that can happen, but the "revolving door" politics. That is individuals switch between roles as politician, regulator, employee and lobbyists.
The point being that especially bigger companies and industries would like to have a direct line towards politics. And as politicians are usually not experts in the field (but politicians), they rely on experts, so there are plenty of advocacy groups that happily supply their "expertise" to them.
The line between "experts" and "advocates" is somewhat blurry. As is the line between "experts" and "regulators" as you need some level of expertise to make good regulations, while having companies and industries regulate themselves usually results in them NOT regulating themselves which can result in problems for workers, consumers, the environment and so on.
Also politicians are themselves some kind of "experts", namely in terms of how the game of politics works. So there's quite some interest in getting politicians as advisors for advocacy groups in terms of how to more effectively advertise. Or you know as a form of more covert bribery. So after a career as politicians they might take a few years off, on a well paid do-nothing-job for a company, to then go into lobbying or to re-enter politics and surprisingly have one's agenda align with that of one's former employer. Or maybe a job as regulator given that they have both the political and the "practical experience" to qualify for such a job.
And so it's quite interesting what kind of shadowy networks are at play and who regularly meets with whom and how their CVs overlap. Requiring lobbyists to register their advocacy intents makes that a little more transparent.
That being said, it might just be that the actual interesting stuff is discussed at dinner or in the lobby, while official events are probably boring presentations just to get that foot in the door and develop contacts and relations.

The "lobby" reference to a physical place is not purely figurative or archaic. A book length account of lobbying in the 1980s (often in the hallways of Congress from which the book takes its name) can be found at: https://www.amazon.com/Showdown-Gucci-Gulch-Lawmakers-Lobbyists/dp/0394758110 I had a law partner who was a lobbyist (in the aughts) and she spent plenty of time, literally, hanging out in the hallways outside committee hearing rooms and the offices of elected officials.


What really goes on in these lobbying sessions?

Lobbyists do lots of things, but this answer focuses on the lobbying events or sessions in particular. Donations and organizing grass roots or astroturf campaigns on particular bills, and strategy sessions with clients, and building coalitions, which are other lobbyist tasks, mostly happen outside these sessions.
Sharing Information
Mostly it is informational and sales pitch oriented. The lobbyists try to come across as factual in a effort to be persuasive, and as much as anything, to get people with power to understand issues from the perspective of their worldview.
Suppose that you are a lobbyist who provides telephone services for prisons. Some of your pitch would be that:

It would cost lots of government money for the government to provide this for free to inmates, and government contracts are often expensive, in a well documents and exact sounding way.

It would emphasize how much more inmates are able to communicate with their loved ones and lawyers by talking on the phone with them as opposed to requiring them to meet in person at the jail or prison, monetizing both possibilities and emphasize what a bargain it is to be able to talk to lawyers on the phone rather than have them charge hundreds of dollars an hour to visit in person.

It would emphasize that prison phones need special features to record and monitor conversations, while keeping attorney calls confidential, that make it different and more expensive than a regular phone so that comparing the costs of regular phones to prison phones isn't apples to apples.

It would note that the administrative costs of handling short, low dollar transaction per transaction are much higher per call than options like monthly phone plans.

It would list a parade of horribles when inmates committed horrible crimes or orchestrated gang violence with unauthorized phones in a well documented list of incidents from anywhere in the world that it happened and how important it is to prevent this from happening.

It would have a comment or two and closing slide of all the groups that support them, e.g., the prison guard's union and law enforcement lobbies.


A short list of the top one or two points would also be part of a lobbyist's elevator pitch to anyone who will listen for a minute or two, and the lobbyist would have a flyer or website link or something to make it easy for a powerful person to access these talking points.
The session would also have swag, food, coffee, or any other kind of showmanship that would make the session more memorable.
Maintaining Familiarity With The Lobbyist
Lobbyists want decision-makes to remember who they are (they were usually once active in politics), and to see them as a resource if the decision-maker has questions about anything (even non-client related) or wants help with anything (even if non-client related).
Lobbyists also look for any opportunity to do a favor for a decision-maker (short of an actual quid pro quo illegal bribe) in order to create a sense of moral obligation to them from the decision-maker, even if the obligation is only strong enough to buy them access with an opportunity to make a future pitch when needed, rather than to actually cause a decision-maker to make a decision in their favor.
Events provide a structured way for a lobbyist to stay visible to decision-makers.
Putting Faces, Human Stories, And Good Vibes Together With Issues
Lobbyists at these sessions try to associate their client's causes with likable, memorable real human beings (ideally while sweet children in tow) who are constituents, perhaps employees of the company or people influenced by the decision.
Any room to link an issue to an identify human interest story, or to make the client look like a good citizen (even in ways unrelated to the issues at hand) is encouraged.
If the decision-maker has a positive impression of the lobbyist's client, the decision-maker will do their best not to harm the lobbyist's client.
This is done so that the decision-maker is blatantly made aware that any decision made has a real impact on real people, rather than only impacting faceless associations and corporations.
Suggesting Alternatives
If it looks like a lobbying client's position isn't going to prevail, the lobbyist wants to plant the seed that there is a controversy and that the decision needs to be postponed until a committee can study it.
Alternatively, the lobbyist might propose another option as a substitute to the action or bill that the client doesn't like, which also isn't desirable for the client but isn't as bad as what would happen otherwise.
If the corrections department is considering changing its rules to allow inmates to use qualified text message only phones that cc every message to a prison guard paid for by family members, the lobbyist might urge instead that it have a monopoly on selling those phones by having the rules impose minimum hardware standards that only the client can meet.
Planting Seeds
Lobbyists at events try to hint at future initiatives that make be taken for a client in a positive light, even if there is not an action item to be taken at the moment.
Identifying Supported and Opposed Action Items
Another key point for a lobbyist is to make sure that any time that a powerful person makes a decision contrary to the interests of their clients that the powerful person is doing so consciously and knowing that this decision is strongly opposed by someone with an intense political interest in preventing it.
A typical client might have 1-3 bills, or tiny riders to bills, or executive branch actions that they really care about in a legislative session.
Lobbyists want to clearly get across the core message of their position on these items, even if they do nothing else. Thus, something like:

The Association of Correctional Telecommunications Providers opposed minority amendment 342 to the Corrections Department Appropriations Bill.

This message, especially needs to get to the people making that decision as close to the time that they are making that decision and as close to the time that they are making up their minds on how to vote on it, as possible.
Ideally, before the appropriations bill even makes it to legislators, the lobbyist identifies who in the executive branch is formulating the Governor's correction budget proposal and tries to pitch their story to that person before the Governor's proposal even arrives at the state house for legislators to consider, hopefully, discouraging bills contrary to the client from ever ending upon on the agenda with the information and worldview provided above, and by signaling that if the proposed budget contains provisions that their client dislikes that there will be a full court press of lobbying opposing the appropriations for their agency when the legislative consideration of the Governor's budget proposal for that agency begins.
Usually lobbying is towards the executive or legislative branch
Most lobbying is towards the executive or legislative branch. Lobbying of the judicial branch has mostly evolved into the profession of law which strongly prohibits ex parte communications (i.e. out of court communications without the other side present) about actual cases.
At most, lobbying of judges is pretty much limited to sharing information not specific to any one case as background worldview framing sessions, maintaining lobbyist familiarity, and humanizing causes.
